# Unable to clone git via SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, git, macos, ssh, ssh-tunnel

**TLDR**

I am trying to ssh tunnel in from my linux machine into a OSx machine that has access to my VPN. This is the URL that I need access `github.someprivateurl.net`.

## The actual problem in details.

**Setting up tunnel**

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ ssh -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.1.18
Password:
Last login: Thu Jun  7 01:00:34 2018 from 192.168.1.3
hutber@Jamies-Mac ~ $ 
hutber@Jamies-Mac ~/www/jamie $ git clone ssh://git@github.someprivateurl.net/Mortgages/mortgages.git
Cloning into 'mortgages-ui'...
remote: Counting objects: 63823, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (52/52), done.
^Cfatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyMiB | 8.44 MiB/s
```

^ is just to show that when ssh'd into the OSx I am able to clone within this machine.

**Accessing the tunnel**

```
hutber@hutber /var/www $ git clone ssh://git@github.someprivateurl.net:3333/Mortgages/mortgages-ui.git


Cloning into 'mortgages-ui'...
```

The above clone on my linux machine will hang until the connection realises it doesn't have access and throws me out.

I'm not sure how helpful this is... But I am unable to reach the site I am trying to clone, so its obviously nothing to do with git:

OSx

```
hutber@Jamies-Mac ~/www/jamie $ ping github.someprivateurl.net
PING github.someprivateurl.net (10.113.188.195): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ping github.someprivateurl.net
```

Linux

```
hutber@hutber /var/www $ ping -p 3333 github.someprivateurl.net
PATTERN: 0x3333
PING github.someprivateurl.net (159.34.88.181) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.24.82 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From 172.16.24.82 icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From 172.16.24.82 icmp_seq=3 Time to live exceeded
From 172.16.24.82 icmp_seq=4 Time to live exceeded
^C
--- github.someprivateurl.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3004ms
```

How can I clone the repo on my linux machine whilst ssh'd into OSx?

**Update**

As this is I believe just a SSH error. I should mention, that the SSh is actually through Host to guest SSH. My guest has a host-only connection and is connected to the internet via its own physical wifi dongle. Its the wifi connection that the VPN is setup.

---

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ ssh -fNT -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.1.18
Password:
hutber@hutber /var/www $ ssh -p 3333 github.someprivateurl.net
^C //Hangs
hutber@hutber /var/www $ telnet localhost 3333
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-libssh_0.7.0
^^
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: As with any git + ssh error, it's simplest to debug it as an ssh problem. First, verify that you can actually ssh to the machine via port 3333. Pinging is insufficient, actually `ssh -p 3333 <host>`.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern `hutber@hutber /var/www $ ssh -p 3333 hutber@192.168.238.130
ssh: connect to host 192.168.238.130 port 3333: No route to host
hutber@hutber /var/www $ ssh -p 3333 192.168.238.130
ssh: connect to host 192.168.238.130 port 3333: No route to hos`

Comment: Yup. As I suspected, the tunnel isn't working. Debug it as an ssh problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *`$ ping -p 3333 github.someprivateurl.net`*

`-p` does not mean the port to ping. It means... something else. So that's not checking if port 3333 is open, you're just pinging the machine in a weird way.

Your git ssh URL is incorrect. Rather than using port 3333 on the remote host you're tunneling to, you have to tell it to use localhost's port 3333.

```
git clone ssh://git@localhost:3333/Mortgages/mortgages-ui.git
```

As with most git+ssh problems, it's easiest to debug them as ssh problems. First is to actually try sshing to port 3333.

```
ssh -p 3333 localhost
```

I suspect that's not going to work. From there, debug the ssh problem normally.

I suspect your tunnel is not actually running because your tunnel shut down as soon as you logged out of the ssh session it opened. You need some extra flags to make it persist as a tunnel. Specifically...

- `-f` to tell `ssh` to go to the background immediately
- `-N` to stop it from trying to execute a remote command
- `-T` to not allocate a pseudo-terminal do handle typing

So that's...

```
ssh -fNT -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.1.18
```

You'll also want to look into using [`autossh`](https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/) to keep the connection up for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping buddy. `Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.`

Comment: @JamieHutber Did you include `-N`?

Comment: Thumbs Up, it was lowercase N when I did it. I have updated the question with a bit more information that is formatted. It appears to hand, the `ssh -p...`

Comment: @JamieHutber I also noticed your ssh URL is not correct. You need to ssh to localhost port 3333. My mistake.

Comment: Interesting indeed.... `hutber@hutber /var/www $ ssh -p 3333 localhost
Permission denied (publickey).` So now my linux machine is trying to connect to the OSx without me providing a key. I need to add a key in my .ssh/config?

Comment: Its running here: `25582 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh -fNT -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.1.18`

Comment: @JamieHutber When you setup the tunnel it connects to `hutber@192.168.1.18`, so it needs authentication for `hutber@192.168.1.18`. When you `ssh -p 3333 localhost` that is using the existing connection to `hutber@192.168.1.18` to ssh to `github.someprivateurl.net`. You still need your authentication for `github.someprivateurl.net`. That is, I guess, a key (which is good). You also might need to specify that you want to ssh as `git` so `ssh -p 3333 git@localhost`. [More can be found in Github's help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172659/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-schwern).

Comment: The key I was missing was that the runnel address `github.someprivateurl.net` is then linked to my `localhost` on the Linux machine.

Comment: Hey again Schwen... Just one quick one from me. With ssh, if it is behind a VPN, I assume the VPN could block all port 22.. It seems now I can't access 22 at all.

Comment: It depends on how the VPN is set up. A VPN is an encrypted tunnel that pretends network traffic from your computer is coming from the VPN's network. If the ssh tunnel is to get to a machine that has a VPN connection, it would be simpler to run the VPN instead of ssh tunneling to a machine that's running the VPN.

Comment: Ye, I don't have any control over the VPN. Actually what the reason for this whole thing is I won't use OSx, so I am running the VPN inside a VM and need the host to have access to certain URL's. Pulse only runs in OSx, there is no Linux support you see. So this is the reason for the VPN tunneling. If there is another way to access the URL in the host I would be all ears :)

Comment: @JamieHutber Simplest would be to use OS X if that's what your work has decided to use, it sounds like your setup will lead to even more problems. If not, it seems [Pulse can run on Linux](https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB40126/).

Comment: Ha, so my work colleagues keep telling me. I'll quit before I have to work on OSx :) I did actually get pulse working, but our work has set up 4 checks that pulse will do before it is allowed to connect, Mcafee, filevault, root password, something else I can't remember... But I appreciate you taking the time. What I am finding the most confusing thing is the fact that with the same machine, the SSH tunnel works on my home Internet. But when I am connected to the work's Guest network it does now. So it is not the VPN that is blocking the ssh connection... I am miffed as to what it could be!?

Comment: @JamieHutber As an old Unix & Mac person, I suggest you consider if this is the best use of your time and your co-workers' and employer's time.

Comment: You are not wrong, but having been told in no uncertain terms that I can use linux. I honestly would rather just leave if I can't get it work. I don't disagree with your statement. I am lucky enough to be able to leave without there being a problem in time off. So I will have to try and work out why the work network is different from my home network.